# Getting the Navbar links to show up on mobiles, one below the other

Tags: html, css

How do I get the links to show up on mobiles (it is not being seen right now on mobile devices), one below the other (on laptops and desktops, the links display horizontally now). I am still learning, but I have learnt enough to do HTML and implement some of the things that have been told on stackoverflow about HTML codes, CSS and JavaScript.

```
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="row">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar">.
 </span>
    <span class="icon-bar">
 </span>
    <span class="icon-bar">
 </span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html  "><img src="images/a1-logo.jpg"/></a>
</div>

 <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none; list-style-position: outside; font-family: &quot;verdana&quot;; font-size: 18px; color: black;"><font face="verdana" size="4"><a href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    </font><li style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none; list-style-position: outside; font-family: &quot;verdana&quot;; font-size: 18px; color: black;"><font face="verdana" size="4"><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    </font><li style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none; list-style-position: outside; font-family: &quot;verdana&quot;; font-size: 18px; color: black;"><font face="verdana" size="4"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    </font><li style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none; list-style-position: outside; font-family: &quot;verdana&quot;; font-size: 18px; color: black;"><font face="verdana" size="4"><a href="Homeopathy-2.html">Homeopathy</a></li>
    </font><li style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none; list-style-position: outside; font-family: &quot;verdana&quot;; font-size: 18px; color: black;"><font face="verdana" size="4"><a href="testimonial.html">Testimonials</a></li>
    </font><li style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none; list-style-position: outside; font-family: &quot;verdana&quot;; font-size: 18px; color: black;"><font face="verdana" size="4"><a href="biz.html">Biz Offers</a></li>
    </font><li style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none; list-style-position: outside; font-family: &quot;verdana&quot;; font-size: 18px; color: black;"><font face="verdana" size="4"><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav><!-- /.nav -->
```

Comment: Only the first 3lines are CSS

Comment: Could you perhaps show us your `style.css` file?

Comment: Hi Ramaanand, welcome at SO! Your CSS is not accessible to use, please post a [reprex]

Comment: This is all:- <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: As you are learning: add something like `.nav li { padding: 0; list-style-type: none; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: black; }` to your CSS and remove all the `<font></font>` from the `<ul><li>` structure, because now you have a lot of redundant code.

Comment: We need to see the content of the CSS, not the link

Comment: If I need to add some more CSS to the header section, please let me know

Comment: That is the (Spartan) content Rene

Comment: Even if it were the Ben Hur version, add your CSS to the snippet above already, that's where the culprit is to be found! ;-) And did you read [reprex], as it will help you focus and maybe even find the cause yourself.... Selfmedication? (I read profiles....)

Comment: The <li...... already had the font and size, so I removed the extra <font> and </font>. What can I do next?

Comment: is there somewhere that we can test it?

Comment: My final comment: for our help you need to comply with several requests made before: add the content of 'css/style.css' to your snippet otherwise we have no way of helping you. Client on the phone: my leg hurts, help me. Doc: come and see me in the office. Client: my leg hurts, what can it be. Doc: come and see me in the office. Client: but my leg hurts. Doc: come and see me in the office.... See whats going on??

Answer (score 0):

The below will make your nav bar list items appear in mobile as a column, the `align-items` and `justify-content` will center items to both X and Y, remove them if not needed.
The media query `@media` will kick in when the device width is `768px` which usually used for a default tablet width.

```
ul.nav {
  display: flex;
  // set direction of children to column based
  flex-direction: column;

  // if you wish to center items along X and Y axis
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  ul.nav {
    // change direction of children to row based
    flex-direction: row;
    
    // you can then unset align and justify if needed or used
    align-items: unset;
    justify-content: unset;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver Heward. I was able to set it right by following the instructions here: www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp